# Why is there a difference between the Java runtime maximum memory on a GitLab CI instance and on a local computer?

Tags: java, memory, gitlab, continuous-integration, jvm

I used the following maven command to run a test and specify the JVM maximum memory :

```bash
mvn clean test -Dtest=TestLoad -DargLine="-Xmx512m -Xms512m" --settings settings.xml
```

I printed the memory in the console using the following java code in my program :

```java
OperatingSystemMXBean osBean = (OperatingSystemMXBean) ManagementFactory.getOperatingSystemMXBean();
        System.out.println("Total physical memory: " + osBean.getTotalMemorySize() + " bytes");
        System.out.println("Total JVM memory: " + Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory() + " bytes");
```

(I used the openjdk 17.0.2 2022-01-18)

Since I specify the JVM memory to 512m, the Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory() should print 536870912 bytes (since 512m = 512 * 1024 * 1024 = 536870912 bytes). And it does on my local computer.

```
[INFO] Running ch.heia.isc.gl2.simulife.TestLoad
Total physical memory: 16564649984 bytes
Total JVM memory: 536870912 bytes
```

But on the GitLab CI instance with the same settings, the memory printed is 518979584 bytes.

```
[INFO] Running ch.heia.isc.gl2.simulife.TestLoad
Total physical memory: 3703250944 bytes
Total JVM memory: 518979584 bytes
```

I couldn't find an entry in the Java documentation that addressed this inconsistency, so I wanted to ask if you had an idea.

Comment: First of all, welcome to stackoverflow. [No images should be uploaded](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors) that could not also be integrated as source code or error text.

Comment: Oh right, my bad. I'll fix that.